# NgbDatepicker markDisabled does not have scope of its parent component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to get this to work:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xIc89cfoD1R8qn8Ojrht?p=preview

To trigger the error, try to open the calendar.

Basically the `markDisabled` callback doesn't have access to the component its being called in.

I believe it SHOULD, yeah? Is this a problem with how `ng-bootstrap` implemented this?

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing methods in Angular doesn't usually work this way (in my experience).

To get things like this to work, I assign the method to a variable instead:

```
isDisabled = (date: NgbDateStruct, current: {month: number}) => {
    console.log('Allow Weekend', this.allowWeekend);
    return date.month !== current.month;
}
```